# android how to know if i have location available

Tags: android, gps, location

i've made a listener that checks is the GPS status is changed..
i want the listener to check if the phone is able get location at all, if now throw gps, then throw cellolar cell..
how can i add it to my listener ?

my listener:

```
locMgr.addGpsStatusListener(new GpsStatus.Listener() 
    { 
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) 
        { 
                switch(event) 
                { 
                        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED: 
                            locationStatus.setText("Location is On");   
                                break ; 
                        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED: 
                             locationStatus.setText("Location is Off");  
                                break ; 
                } 
        }
    }) ;
```

Comment: Do you mean if it has GPS built in? Or do you mean you want to request the location of a device, and be notified when one has been found?

Comment: i want to check the availability to get the user location.
throw gps or throw phone location.
ths listener gives me the gps status. i want know add a listener to see if the network cell can provide me location (without gps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a class

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        /**
         * This function handles location change event if location is found
         */
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {...
```

Now, whenever you'll get some GPS location, it'll come inside `onLocationChanged()` method.

Do not forget to add the following permissions in your manifest-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Also make sure you are adding both the location listeners GPS as well as Network like-

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, locListener);
```

Comment: ok your code here will give me location changes.
but what i wanted to check, that i'm even able to get those update.
same as the gps staus listener - just for locations..

Comment: i want to know if i'm conneceted to any location provider. no metter if its gps or other location provider. i want to know the state...

Comment: You mean something like this: ((LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)).isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you would like to know specific provider availability, you could use:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); //or other provider.
```

And track its availability using `LocationListener` callbacks:

```
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
```

Ofcourse you will need a propriate location permissions in your manifest.